# Does relay supported in the On-Premises Service Bus 1.1 SDK (Not Azure Cloud)

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

Does relay supported in the On-Premises Service Bus 1.1 SDK (Not Azure Cloud)

Below code works fine when hosted in Azure Cloud Service Bus but does not work in the On-Premises Service Bus 1.1.

**Code:**

```
ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.AutoDetect;
string serviceNamespace = "ServiceBusDefaultNamespace";
string issuerName = "owner";
string issuerSecret = "[Secret Key Here]";
ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.AutoDetect;
var address = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", serviceNamespace,    "EchoService");
var binding = new NetTcpRelayBinding();
var behavior = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior(); 

binding.Security.Mode = EndToEndSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.RelayClientAuthenticationType =     RelayClientAuthenticationType.RelayAccessToken;

behavior.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(issuerName,   issuerSecret);
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(EchoService));
var endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IEchoContract), binding, address);
endpoint.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
host.Open();
```

**Error while instantiating the ServiceHost**

Answer (score 0):

Windows Service Bus 1.1 doesn't support Relay but only queue-based messaging.

This question has already been asked and answered here: [Relay binding not working for Window Server Service Bus 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157201/relay-binding-not-working-for-window-server-service-bus-1-1)